# Delphi TButton component styling

Tags: delphi, button, delphi-7, vcl, tbutton

I just want to apologize in advance if this question is already in another thread. I am also relatively new to Delphi.

Today I have seen an example Delphi program that has `TButton` components on it. The buttons have a pulsating blue effect that I assume is part of the Windows styling. There is absolutely no code written to make the button this way. I have searched for a possible setting but to no avail.

Note: The buttons make the effect at run-time and there are no custom components installed.

If someone could give me some information about how to do this without code, maybe just a setting would be great.

I am using Delphi 7 (2002).

Comment: It seems you have left your previous question in a kind of  'dangling' state. Please revisit.

Comment: That is implemented in the Windows BUTTON control code

Comment: Can you specify the Windows button control code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi Firemonkey (FMX) component framework has a `TColorAnimation` for which you can set properties like Duration, StartValue, StopValue, trigger etc. The FMX framework was introduced in Delphi XE2.

[Blinking button demo](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/vsevolodleonov/2012/04/12/fm_blinking_button_eng/)

---

Now that you have clarified that you use Delphi 7 (please remember in future to indicate the version), here's an alternative that works in Delphi 7 (FMX is not compatible with Delphi 7)

```
var
  b: boolean;

procedure TForm9.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  b := not b;
  if b then
    Button1.Perform(BM_SETSTATE, 0, 0)
  else
    Button1.Perform(BM_SETSTATE, 1, 0);
end;
```

Flashing is controlled by a TTimer, e.g 500 ms.

However, this doesn't fulfill your requirement of *"There is absolutely no code written to make the button this way."*, but I'm not aware of any way to achieve that.

Comment: Is it possible to do a windows style blinking button without any components. And is FireMonkey compatible with Delphi 7?

Comment: Thank you Tom! I will definitely use the code since I could find anything else.